# python all possible combinations of 0,1 of length k

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I need all possible combinations of 0,1 of length k.

Suppose k=2 I want   `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)`

I have tried different function in `itertools` but I did not find what I want.

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([0,1], 2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
>>> list(itertools.product([0,1], [0,1])) #does not work if k>2
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: by quick I meant computationally quick :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) takes a `repeat` keyword argument; set it to `k`:

```
product(range(2), repeat=k)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for k in range(2, 5):
...     print list(product(range(2), repeat=k))
... 
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```