# Finding combinations where the length of the combination is more then the variables being used

Tags: python-2.7, math, python-itertools

I'm trying to get 5 length combinations out of a list of 2 can't find anything that works.

```
x = [5,7]
abc = list(itertools.combinations((x),5))
```

All I get is []

Hoping to get every possible combinations of [5,7] but with a length of 5 like [5,7,7,5,7].

Is seems possible, I've tried alot of different things.

once again, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get `[]` is indeed (as the title suggests) you want a length longer than the number of elements. Whereas, [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) says:

> itertools.combinations(iterable, r):
>
> Return r length **subsequences** of elements from the input iterable.

I guess what you need is [another function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) (next paragraph in the doc):

```
>>> x = [5, 7]
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement((x),5))                        
[(5, 5, 5, 5, 5), (5, 5, 5, 5, 7), (5, 5, 5, 7, 7), (5, 5, 7, 7, 7), (5, 7, 7, 7, 7), (7, 7, 7, 7, 7)]
>>>
```

Or, as your example suggests, maybe you do not want combinations but permutations? Problem is, it doesn't seem to be possible to do the same as for combinations. But maybe a [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will do the trick?

```
>>> list(itertools.product(x, repeat=5))
[(5, 5, 5, 5, 5), (5, 5, 5, 5, 7), (5, 5, 5, 7, 5), (5, 5, 5, 7, 7), (5, 5, 7, 5, 5), (5, 5, 7, 5, 7), (5, 5, 7, 7, 5), (5, 5, 7, 7, 7), (5, 7, 5, 5, 5), (5, 7, 5, 5, 7), (5, 7, 5, 7, 5), (5, 7, 5, 7, 7), (5, 7, 7, 5, 5), (5, 7, 7, 5, 7), (5, 7, 7, 7, 5), (5, 7, 7, 7, 7), (7, 5, 5, 5, 5), (7, 5, 5, 5, 7), (7, 5, 5, 7, 5), (7, 5, 5, 7, 7), (7, 5, 7, 5, 5), (7, 5, 7, 5, 7), (7, 5, 7, 7, 5), (7, 5, 7, 7, 7), (7, 7, 5, 5, 5), (7, 7, 5, 5, 7), (7, 7, 5, 7, 5), (7, 7, 5, 7, 7), (7, 7, 7, 5, 5), (7, 7, 7, 5, 7), (7, 7, 7, 7, 5), (7, 7, 7, 7, 7)]
```

EDIT: isn't your question really really close to this one: [python all possible combinations of 0,1 of length k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991292/python-all-possible-combinations-of-0-1-of-length-k?rq=1)